# Interpretation of one single handwritten word

Tags: handwriting, kurrent, interpretation

In the attached and below deciphered text, I have problems with interpreting one single word, marked with XXX. Any suggestions?:

*Sie — und noch mehr Andere — werden vielleicht finden, dass die Abhandlung zu viel XXX Ontologie oder Metaphysik enthalte, was allerdings nicht nach dem Geschmacke jetziger Zeit ist.  Allein man wird mir einräumen, ...*

[image]

Comment: No perfect and convincing word comes to my mind. Just two *cautious guesses* with no claim to definitive accuracy. (1) "spinöse", adj. (=spitzfindig, schwierig). In this reading, "sp" would overlay and replace a preexisting letter (maybe an "O" as in Ontologie). (2) "Kinese", n. The starting letter *does* look a lot like a capital "K" to me. If you have other "K"s in the letter, maybe try and compare them.

Comment: (the frequency of "spinös" since 1800: https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dta%2Bdwds&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1800%3A1999&q1=spin%C3%B6s)

Comment: @Marquinho, Thank you, once again, Marquinho. I think "spinöse" makes good sense, both "on the merits" and based upon a visual interpretation. - By the way, you might find my email address in my profile. Helge

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is just a service request. There is nothing general to be learned here, and no one with a similar request might find his answer here. Those questions just don't fit well to the side, while many users have fun, trying to help solving them.

Comment: I think the word before is not "viel". It looks like "seine" but the agreement is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

(I'm making my old comment into an answer for the sake of visibility.)

The word most likely reads "[**spinöse**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/spin%C3%B6s)" (*adj.*, syn. "schwierige, spitzfindige"), yielding the phrase

> zu viel *spinöse* Ontologie oder Metaphysik

i.e., in context:

> [You might find that there is] too much *abstruse/difficult/hair-splitting* ontology or metaphysics [for today's taste in the treatise.]

The beginning of the word – the sign(s) coming before  "-in-" – is hardest to decipher.
The sign(s) display some of the hallmarks of each of the following capital letters in Kurrentschrift: **O**, **Q**, **K** or **R**. However, none of these (at least in their usual forms) is a perfect fit.

Rather than a single letter, what we have here is a capital "**O**" overlaid with, and in fact *overwritten* by, the group "**sp**". Subtracting the "O" (compare the one in "Ontologie") leaves the letters "sp" and yields "spinöse".

The phaenomenon is easily explained: the writer corrected his first version

> (1) zu viel O[ntologie]

into

> (2) zu viel spinöse Ontologie

that is, he added in the adjective.

It is my understanding that OP was asking about a ["philosophy related letter written during the 19th century"](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/38535/helge), as in his other questions.
The adj. "spinös" was uncommon, though demonstrably in use, in the 19th century, according to this [frequency analysis](https://www.dwds.de/r/plot/?view=1&corpus=dta%2Bdwds&norm=date%2Bclass&smooth=spline&genres=0&grand=1&slice=10&prune=0&window=3&wbase=0&logavg=0&logscale=0&xrange=1800%3A1999&q1=spin%C3%B6s) in the DWDS.

Comment: Very plausibly the correct answer, especially if you have a look at the other handwritten texts posted by the OP.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**:

Consider the answer by [marquinho](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/69330/25156), as it fits better with the age of the other handwritten documents posted by the OP.

**Original answer**:

---

From the context it should be the abbreviation `Quines.` and thus would refer to Quine's meta-ontology.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willard_Van_Orman_Quine

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-Ontologie#Quineanischer_Ansatz

Since a German speaker would pronounce that name *Kine* or *Kinä* I guess the `K` below the `Qu` was just an honest spelling mistake.

[image: I see a Q below the K, also the ink is thicker there, indicating a quick correction]

However, that would place the handwritten text well after 1934, when Quine wrote his first essay on this topic.
If this is the case I think my answer is correct.

Comment: "that would place the handwritten text well after 1934": My understanding is that [OP](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/38535/helge) was asking about a letter by a late-19th-century philosophy (metaphysics) professor (d. 1897), in this as in the [other](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/67868/transcription-of-letter-in-kurrent-ca-1880-difficult-word) cases. This rules out Quine. – As an aside, this sample looks like a pretty typical *19th century* Kurrentschrift *to me* (might be subjective, though); a style that would have been all but extinct by then ("well after 1934").

Comment: Very good argument!

Comment: Thank you – and thanks for the nice mention in your edit!